# How to have fixed text animation change when using fullpage.js scrolling between sections and then disappear passing a certain section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

currently I have a fixed text animation just infinitely looping over top of my fullpage wrapper. I want to have it so that my text animation only changes when I scroll from section to section. I'm also trying to have it disappear after I scroll away from section2 onto section3. I'm a little confused as to make this happen...

currently

```
<body>
<div class="featuredtitle">
      <div class="visable">
        <ul>
         <li><h1>nameone</h1></li>
         <li><h1>nametwo</h1></li>
         <LI><h1>namethree</h1></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="fullpage">
   <div class="section active" id="section0"></div>
   <div class="section" id="section1"></div>
   <div class="section" id="section2"></div>
   <div class="section" id="section3"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

text animation: http://codepen.io/yoannhel/pen/sJpDj

sorry if im doing this wrong first time posting on here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an example within [the examples folder of fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples). 
The filename is "callbacks.html".Check it out.

You can make use of fullPage.js [callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) to fire them, or even to [the state classes added to the body element](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) if you want to fire them with CSS.

Check also [this example regarding the fullPage.js callbacks](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/callbacks.html)

In your case it seems you would like to use the `onLeave` callback.